# PHP getdate() not returning the same day/month when used at two separate places in my code

Tags: php, sql-server, date, datetime, web

I have a function that calls another function to write some values into an MSSQL database. It takes the string request as first argument and an array containing the values to enter in the query (where there are ? in the query) if these are contained in a variable and cannot be explicitly written in the query. Here is the function in question:

```
public function dbInsert(){
    $curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST ".
        "(DATE_RECU, DATE_TERMINEE, USER_ID, STATUS) ".
        "VALUES(?, '', ?, 'R');", array($curr_date, $this->userId));
    $mr_select = $this->db->query("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC;",
            array($this->userId));
    $mr_result = $mr_select->result_array();
    $mr_id = $mr_result[0]['ID'];

    $sim = 'N/A';
    if(isset($this->recurrenceType))
        $sim = 'Recurrent';

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.REQUEST ".
        "(USER_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, REQUEST_END_DATE, MODEL, EXPERIMENT, VARIABLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, ".
        "LON_FROM, LAT_FROM, LON_TO, LAT_TO, RESOLUTION, FORMAT, SIMULATION, STATUS, ".
        "CANCELLED_YN, PROJECT, MR_ID, URL_ORIGIN, DATE_EMAIL) ".
        "VALUES(?, ?, '', ?, 'N/A', 'N/A', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', 0, 'N/A', ?, ?, ?);",
        array($this->userId, $curr_date, $this->model, $this->startDate, $this->endDate, 
                $this->lonFrom, $this->latFrom, $this->lonTo, $this->latTo, 
                $this->resolution, $this->format, $sim, $mr_id, $this->url_origin, $this->date_email));

    $r_select = $this->db->query("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM DAI_REQ.REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC;",
            array($this->userId));
    $r_result = $r_select->result_array();
    $this->id = $r_result[0]['ID'];
}
```

As you can see, I call the `query` function two times, and within those two queries I use the variable `$curr_date` that contains the date of today. Unfortunately, when I go look into the database with sql-server after running this code, the date I see in the `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` table is not the same as the date in the `DAI_REQ.REQUEST` table. The latter contains the good date while the former contains a random date (though the date is similar each day I try it). For exemple, the latter would `2014-06-30 14:08:40.427` and the former would be `2014-02-19 00:00:00.000`

I also have to mention that we have two servers (so two databases also), one for development and one for public deployment. The problem I am describing occurs on the public deployment server, but not on the development server.

I have also tried to remove the use of the `$curr_date` variable by directly calling the `getdate()` function inside the `query` function as follows:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST ".
    "(DATE_RECU, DATE_TERMINEE, USER_ID, STATUS) ".
    "VALUES(GETDATE(), '', ?, 'R');", array($this->userId));
...
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.REQUEST ".
    "(USER_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, REQUEST_END_DATE, MODEL, EXPERIMENT, VARIABLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, ".
    "LON_FROM, LAT_FROM, LON_TO, LAT_TO, RESOLUTION, FORMAT, SIMULATION, STATUS, ".
    "CANCELLED_YN, PROJECT, MR_ID, URL_ORIGIN, DATE_EMAIL) ".
    "VALUES(?, GETDATE(), '', ?, 'N/A', 'N/A', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', 0, 'N/A', ?, ?, ?);",
    array($this->userId, $this->model, $this->startDate, $this->endDate, 
            $this->lonFrom, $this->latFrom, $this->lonTo, $this->latTo, 
            $this->resolution, $this->format, $sim, $mr_id, $this->url_origin, $this->date_email));
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Could you post the schema? It's possible the data types are different for the two tables.

Comment: @BA_Webimax I don't have the schema on hand right now, but I can confirm that both fields in `DAI_REQ.REQUEST` and `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` are of the type `(datetime, not null)`

Comment: Your code is naturally subject to race conditions. You're simply ASSUMING that it is impossible for some OTHER record to get inserted into the db for the same user in between the time you do the insert and then the select. This is a **BAD** assumption. You should be using @@IDENTITY or similar to get the id of the record you just inserted.

Comment: @MarcB SCOPE_IDENTITY() is much better, but in either case it must be part of the same batch (currently the code sends two different batches).

Comment: @MarcB @AaronBertrand So instead of writing `$mr_select = $this->db->query("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM AI_REQ.META_REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC;", array($this->userId));` and getting the ID from that query, I should write `$mr_id = $this->db->query("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST');");` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557977/mssql-insert-query-failing-for-a-specific-table-when-called-with-php) for full details.

The reason why I had this behavior is because the row was actually not getting inserted in the `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` on the first `INSERT` query. This was caused by the deployment server's `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` table not being set to auto increment the `ID` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

`getdate()` returns an associative array containing the date information of the timestamp, or the current local time if no timestamp is given.. What you are looking for is [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not resolve the problem. I have replace the line `$curr_date = getdate();` with `$curr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and I have the same behavior.