# MSSQL INSERT query failing for a specific table when called with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, web

I need to read the date that a request was created from our website. When that request is created, the information corresponding to that request and its meta-request is inserted in the `DAI_REQ.REQUEST` and `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` tables, respectively. We also have a dev server and a public deployment server. The problem happens only on our deployment server for some reason..

Unfortunately, the `INSERT` query to insert the information of the meta-request in the `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` table does not work, but the `SELECT` query I do right after does (so in my eyes, this removes any connection problems with the database/table itself). I also use the same syntax as the `INSERT` query I do on the `DAI_REQ.REQUEST`, so I do not think it is a query syntax problem. I also tried manually inserting as line within sql-server and it works fine. Finally, I `echo`'ed the value of `$this->userId` that I use as a parameter for the `INSERT` query to see if it contained the right ID, and it does. I did the same for the return value of `$this->db->query(...)`, and it does NOT return anything (on our deployment server only).

I also know that my way of retrieving the last inserted row in a table is not perfect, but this is not the problem at hand here and it will be changed later on.

Here is the actual code where the problem happens:

```
public function dbInsert(){

    // The actual problematic query
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST ".
        "(DATE_RECU, DATE_TERMINEE, USER_ID, STATUS) ".
        "VALUES(GETDATE(), '', ?, 'R');", array($this->userId));

    // This works fine though
    $mr_select = $this->db->query("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC;",
            array($this->userId));
    $mr_result = $mr_select->result_array();
    $mr_id = $mr_result[0]['ID'];

    $sim = 'N/A';
    if(isset($this->recurrenceType))
        $sim = 'Recurrent';

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO DAI_REQ.REQUEST ".
        "(USER_ID, ASSIGNED_DATE, REQUEST_END_DATE, MODEL, EXPERIMENT, VARIABLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, ".
        "LON_FROM, LAT_FROM, LON_TO, LAT_TO, RESOLUTION, FORMAT, SIMULATION, STATUS, ".
        "CANCELLED_YN, PROJECT, MR_ID, URL_ORIGIN, DATE_EMAIL) ".
        "VALUES(?, GETDATE(), '', ?, 'N/A', 'N/A', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', 0, 'N/A', ?, ?, ?);",
        array($this->userId, $this->model, $this->startDate, $this->endDate, 
                $this->lonFrom, $this->latFrom, $this->lonTo, $this->latTo, 
                $this->resolution, $this->format, $sim, $mr_id, $this->url_origin, $this->date_email));

    $r_select = $this->db->query("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM DAI_REQ.REQUEST WHERE USER_ID = ? ORDER BY ID DESC;",
            array($this->userId));
    $r_result = $r_select->result_array();
    $this->id = $r_result[0]['ID'];
}
```

Comment: What means 'does not work'? Try to run this query in mysql console or phpmyadmin and see what it returns.

Comment: @szymanskilukasz Does not work means the row is not added in the table. I have mentioned in my post already that I DID try adding it manually in sql-server and it DID work there. I am using MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Your two servers are pointing at different databases, correct? Also, when you tried manually putting inserting, does that mean you ran the query from the MS SQL Server application or edited the line from table view?

Comment: @Rickkwa Yes, you are correct. Both databases contain the same table names. All requests work on the dev server, and only the `INSERT` in `DAI_REQ.META_REQUEST` fails on the deployment server, the others work fine.

Comment: @Choub890 I edited my comment before and I guess you didn't see the edit. Can you tell me about how you manually inserted it? Thanks.

Comment: @Rickkwa Yeah sorry, didn't notice your edit. I used Microsoft SQL Server Management application and ran the following query from there: `INSERT INTO [CRIACC_DB].[dai_req].[META_REQUEST] VALUES ('11655', '2014-07-03 10:35:05.000', '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', '1838', 'F')` where CRIACC_DB is the name of the deployment database. This worked.

Comment: @Choub890 Ok. Here's my guess. The deployment server isn't set up to automatically assign the `ID` column when you run a query that doesn't specify the `ID`.

Comment: @Rickkwa Would that be the `Identity` and `Identity Increment` properties on the `ID` field of the table? If so, I guess they have to be set to `true` and `1` respectively right? Because that is a difference between the dev and deployment server database's tables that I can see in Microsoft SQL Server Management

Comment: @Choub890 I think so, I haven't used MSSQL in a while. But yeah, your deployment database has it so that it doesn't increment it automatically for you.

Comment: @Rickkwa I'll test that out and come back to you when I do. I don't have the necessary permissions to modify those properties so I'll ask the appropriate person to do it for me. If it does work, I'll let you know and you'll be able to post that as an answer so I can upvote you and mark your response as the official answer.

Comment: @Rickkwa Yeah, that was it. If you want, post your answer and I'll mark it as the official answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database that the deployment server is using isn't set up to auto increment the `ID` column. In Microsoft SQL Server, for the `ID` column, you can set the `Identity` to `Yes` and `Identity Increment` to whatever number you want the `ID` column to increment by.